# Batch script errorlevel assistance

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, error-handling, batch-processing, return-code

I have two actions happening within a batch script. The first action calls for a .exe file that uses an .xml file to scrub content in files.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=/" %%H in ('DIR /B c:\directory\*') do c:\Progra~1\scrub-prog\scrubber.exe c:\Progra~1\scrub-prog\scrubber.xml c:\%%H
```

The second action is a transmission of the scrubbed files via psftp (putty ftp).

```
echo n | psftp.exe user@hostname.com -i id_rsa.ppk -v -b psftp-rules.txt -bc >> c:\log-file.txt
```

What I need is a way to check the errorlevel of each of these actions separately. If the errorlevel is 0, I need the process to continue and a message of success to be echoed into a file of my choosing.

If the errorlevel is anything other than 0, I need the process to immediately end and exit the script and a message of failure to be echoed into a file of my choosing.

Answer (score 0):

The errorlevel is set in the variable `%errorlevel%` - you can use a simple if statement.

```
if errorlevel 1 echo command failed>>log.txt&goto :EOF
```

alternatively -

```
if %errorlevel%==1 echo command failed>>log.txt&goto :EOF
```

or you could use `||` at the end of the command, any code after `||` will only be executed if an error level is set by the preceding command.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=/" %%H in ('DIR /B c:\directory\*') do (
    c:\Progra~1\scrub-prog\scrubber.exe c:\Progra~1\scrub-prog\scrubber.xml c:\%%H
) || echo command failed>>log.txt&goto :EOF
```

The above will fail exit at the end of the entire for loop, you could do the following if you want to exit at the scrubber command that might fail -

```
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=/" %%H in ('DIR /B c:\directory\*') do c:\Progra~1\scrub-prog\scrubber.exe c:\Progra~1\scrub-prog\scrubber.xml c:\%%H || echo failed at c:\%%H>>log.txt&goto :EOF
```

Comment: `if not %errorlevel%==0 echo command failed>>log.txt&goto :EOF` <-- this is better and will capture any non-zero errorlevel.